# Show that the graph on 99 vertices cannot be divided into two classes

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

In a graph with 99 vertices, two vertices have a degree of 3, and the degree of the other vertices is 4. Show that the graph contains an odd cycle.

I figured I have to show that the graph cannot be divided into two classes meaning
there is an odd cycle , but I cannot show how?(

Comment: Hint: in a bipartite graph, both parts have the same total degree, which is in this case $(97 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 3) / 2 = 197$.